Configure Your Dashboard button is missing
My CiviCRM home page is missing the Configure Your Dashboard button. I can't find anything in the user guide or administrator functions that address this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Where did you see that there should be such a button? There's the "available dashlets" collapsed accordion, but I don't remember there ever being a configure button.
Also what does homepage mean to you? You set the homepage in the CMS so it could really be any page on a given site. There is the url https://example.com/civicrm, which is the civi "dashboard", which I'm referring to above. There is also the "civi user dashboard" at https://example.com/civicrm/user, which is not configurable, but there is a built-in extension you can enable called "User Dashboard" which gives a little settings icon in the top right.

Agreed, any use of "civicrm dashboard" needs to be qualified with "user dashboard" vs. "somethingelse dashboard".

I'm relatively new to this, so apologies if I don't get the terminology right all time. I'm referring to https://example.com/civicrm.
The user guide include this: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/menu-dashboard-and-dashlets/#dashlets
This looks like it's referring to https://example.com/civicrm.  That's where I got the idea that there should be a button for "Configure Your Dashboard".

Oh, hah, that image is at least 9 years old - looks like it might be from version 4.5 of civi (the dates in the screenshot are from 2009 but that might be misleading - it might not be THAT old). It definitely needs updating. See one of the demos for what it currently looks like, e.g. https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org
